# Is there a more beautiful way to convert a character literal to its corresponding escape character?

Tags: rust

I'm writing a parser:

```
match ch  {
    // ...
    'b' => {
        token.push('\b');
        continue;
    },
    'f' => {
        token.push('\f');
        continue;
    },
    'n' => {
        token.push('\n');
        continue;
    },
    'r' => {
        token.push('\r');
        continue;
    },
    't' => {
        token.push('\t');
        continue;
    },
    // ...
},
```

There's a lot of repeating code, so I'm thinking about a more elegant way to do it. I thought something like this would be possible:

```
macro_rules! escaped_match {
    ($char:expr) => (
        '$char' => {
            token.push('\$char')
            continue;
        }
    )
}
```

But my hope is gone:

```
error: character literal may only contain one codepoint: '$
 --> src/main.rs:3:9
  |
3 |         '$char' => {
  |         ^^
```

Is there a more beautiful way to do it, whether using macros, compiler plugins, hacks, or black magic?

Answer (score 4):

Rust macros are not C macros — you cannot create invalid tokens and hope that they are valid sometime in the future. Likewise, they aren't a fancy way of concatenating strings that later get interpreted as code.

Looking at the code, It seems like the main repetition is in the `push` and `continue`. I'd probably use normal functions and pattern matching to DRY up that specific code:

```
fn escape_char(c: char) -> Option<char> {
    Some(match c {
        // 'b' => '\b',
        // 'f' => '\f',
        'n' => '\n',
        'r' => '\r',
        't' => '\t',
        _ => return None,
    })
}

fn main() {
    // ...

    if let Some(escape) = escape_char('b') {
        token.push(escape);
        continue;
    }

    // ...
}
```

Now the mapping is constrained to a single `x => '\y'` line.

Note that `\b` and `\f` aren't recognized escape codes in Rust; not sure what you are going to do for those.

Comment: “Likewise, they aren't a fancy way of concatenating strings.” → Well, there is `concat!`. Sure, it's implemented as a plugin because regular macros can't do it, but the wording is misleading here.